# React-Loadable how to return component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const PageDocuments = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./pages/documentflow/PageDocuments'),
    loading:  ({error}) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
});

<LayoutDefault path={PageDocuments.Path} component={PageDocuments}/>
```

I have error loading(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
How i can use return for get all component?

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all as `loading` property requires you to return a `Component` and you are not returning anything from `loading`.

If you don't want to show a loading component you can return `null`.

You can take a look at this example for more detail: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#loadingcomponent

Here is the doc for the same: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#optsloading

Hope this helps!